# Ansible - XML namespaces

Tags: xml, xpath, ansible

I have a following XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<settings xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/SETTINGS/1.0.0"
     xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
     xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/SETTINGS/1.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/settings-1.0.0.xsd">
   <servers>
     <server>
       <id>nexus-dev-snapshots</id>
       <username>user</username>
       <password>hahah</password>
     </server>
     <server>
        <id>nexus-dev-releases</id>
        <username>user</username>
        <password>hahah</password>
     </server>
   </servers>

   <pluginGroups></pluginGroups>
   <proxies></proxies>
   <mirrors></mirrors>
   <profiles></profiles>
</settings>
```

I am trying to add new elements to **mirrors** with ansible but get error that my path is not correct, I believe somehow it's to do with namespaces because without them it works. Would appreciate some help on it, thank you.

```
 - name: Add a new mirror to the mirrors element
  hosts: localhost
  connection: local
  tasks:
    - name: Add new elements
      xml:
        path: settings.xml
        xpath: /xsi:settings/xsi:mirrors/xsi:mirror/xsi:id
        value: 1
        namespaces: 
          xmlns: http://maven.apache.org/SETTINGS/1.0.0
          xsi: http://maven.apache.org/SETTINGS/1.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/settings-1.0.0.xsd
      xml:
        path: settings.xml
        xpath: /xsi:settings/xsi:mirrors/xsi:mirror/xsi:name
        value: 2
        namespaces:
          xmlns: http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance 
          xsi: http://maven.apache.org/SETTINGS/1.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/settings-1.0.0.xsd
      xml:
        path: settings.xml
        xpath: /xsi:settings/xsi:mirrors/xsi:mirror/xsi:url
        value: 3
        namespaces: 
          xmlns: http://maven.apache.org/SETTINGS/1.0.0
          xsi: http://maven.apache.org/SETTINGS/1.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/settings-1.0.0.xsd
```

With end result:

```
<mirrors>
    <mirror>
      <id>1</id>
      <name>2</name>
      <url>3</url>
      <mirrorOf>*</mirrorOf>
    </mirror>
  </mirrors>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your document is in the `http://maven.apache.org/SETTINGS/1.0.0` namespace.

Your paths should reflect that

```
  tasks:
    - name: Add new elements
      xml:
        path: settings.xml
        xpath: /m:settings/m:mirrors/m:mirror/m:id
        value: 1
        namespaces: 
          m: http://maven.apache.org/SETTINGS/1.0.0
```

The XML document reads

```
<settings xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/SETTINGS/1.0.0">
  <!-- ... -->
</settings>
```

which means that the `settings` element and *everything* it contains belongs to `http://maven.apache.org/SETTINGS/1.0.0` (except it has explicitly declared a different namespace, which is not happening in your document). That's called a "default namespace".

Since it's the default namespace, it has no prefix in the XML. But XPath generally requires a prefix to work - and you're free to pick any prefix and associate it to `http://maven.apache.org/SETTINGS/1.0.0`. I've picked `m:` for brevity.